# Is there a smart way to manage the imports in Java when import path includes version number that changes frequently?

Tags: java, import

Context:
We have Java application on Maven and Spring framework.
We are using a third party library in our project where classes from the library have to be imported this way(for example):

```
import com.doodle.api.v201709.Class1;
```

As a result,whenever there is a version change , it is not only the pom.xml has to be changed but almost all of the classes has to be updated to change the version from v201709 to v201711 for example.

I tried to handle this issue by putting all of these kinds of imports in one class and extending that class in those classes where these imports are required. Seems classes where the imports are required are not getting them and I am seeing compilation failure with  "cannot find symbol" error msg.

Any idea on how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half an answer:

> I tried to handle this issue by putting all of these kinds of imports in one class and extending that class in those classes where these imports are required.

Translates to: you don't know what import statements are and how they are used.

Meaning: import statements are not something that you can pass down using inheritance. They are a purely syntactical thing for human programmers. You import a class such as x.y.Z ... so that you can use `Z` within your source code, instead of writing `x.y.Z` all the time.

The compiled byte code knows **nothing** about imports - they are gone. Instead, the compiled byte code uses `x.y.Z` all the time.

Therefore your idea to "import" names, and using inheritance to sneak the imports into other places, as said: does not work.

And in that sense the real answer is: you have to look into proper tooling that makes it easy to change such things. You probably find such refactoring capabilities within IntelliJ or eclipse. Or, alternatively, you turn to sed/awk and command line magic (it shouldn't be to hard to search for `import x.y.v1.Z` patterns to replace them with `import x.y.v2.Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't give you that flexibility at compile time.

Among alternative options that you have:

1. **Properly version your code**, that of your dependency, then use a build dependency management tool such as Maven. This is safer as it allows version control and possibility to revert to the previous version if the new one doesn't work. This option reduces coupling between the two code bases.
2. **Use scripting**: With something like Groovy, you can take advantage of AST transformations and add dynamic imports at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a class with all the imports and then imported that class wherever required.